# What to do now ''com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator' is deprecated' in Android Java"

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode, zxing

I've been using the 'com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator' in my Android Java project like this:

```java
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(QrCodeActivity.this);
```

How can I replace this functionality in my project now that this class is deprecated?

I have been searching for a solution, but I haven't found one yet. If possible, I would like to continue using ZXing.

Comment: I am no expert for zxing but at least in [this](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) repo it says "Use ScanOptions and ScanContract instead.".

Comment: I think I didn't search correctly in the repository haha, but it helped me a lot, and I was able to resolve this issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As they described in the deprecated class: "**Use ScanOptions and ScanContract instead**" like this way :

initlize the intent in onCreate():

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> scanQrResultLauncher;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    scanQrResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            resultData ->{
                if (resultData.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    ScanIntentResult result = ScanIntentResult.parseActivityResult(resultData.getResultCode(), resultData.getData());

                    //this will be qr activity result
                    if (result.getContents() == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.canceled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else {
                        String qrContents = result.getContents();
                        //TODO Handle qr result here
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

and when you want to start scanner :

```
scanQrResultLauncher.launch(new ScanContract().createIntent(getContext(), new ScanOptions()));
```